# Method is on scope still not getting called from ng-click

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angularjs-ng-click

Below is the HTML that I'm using

```
<div ng-controller="profileEventsCtrl" >
<div class="row mainNavbar" data-ng-show="hideVanityPlate">
<div id="navigatornavbarview" data-ui-view="navigatornavbarview"></div>
</div>
<div class="Profileindex" ng-init="init()">
<div id="profile" style="padding-bottom:20px">
    <div class="col-md-12"> <h1>My Events</h1></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div profile-navigation=""></div>
        </div><!--col-md-2-->
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <accordion close-others="true">
                <accordion-group is-open="status.open" ng-repeat="userEvent in userEvents">
                    <accordion-heading>
                        {{userEvent.Event.Title}}
                        <div class="condensed medium pull-right date">{{userEvent.Event.FormatedEventDateStartToEnd}} &nbsp</div>
                        <div class="condensed medium lineblock">
                            <span class="place ">{{userEvent.Event.Location}}</span> |  <span class="place" ng-click="switchEvent(userEvent.Event.Code)" ><span>{{SwitchEventText}}</span></span>
                        </div>
                    </accordion-heading>
                </accordion-group>
            </accordion>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the controller that I'm using

```
(function (ng, app) {
'use strict';

app.controller('profileEventsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$state', '$rootScope', '$q', '$timeout', 'localization','profileSvcs', profileEventsCtrl]);
function profileEventsCtrl($scope, $location, $state, $rootScope, $q, $timeout, localization, profileSvcs) {
    $scope.userEvents = {};
    $scope.SwitchEventText = "Switch Events"

    $scope.init = function () {
        $rootScope.currentScope = $scope;
        $scope.hideVanityPlate = true;
        $scope.getMyEvents();

    };


    $scope.getMyEvents = function () {
        profileSvcs.getMyEvents().then(function (response) {
            $scope.userEvents = response.data;
        });
    }

    $scope.switchEvent = function (eventCode) {
        var newLocationHash = "/" + $rootScope.cultureCode + "/navigator/" + eventCode + "/profile";
        $location.path(newLocationHash);
    }



}    
})(angular, app);
```

All the other components are working fine. The data is getting loaded from API and getting populated. But `ng-click` doesn't work. I don't event get any console errors hence getting difficult to debug.

Also to test whether or not the function `switchEvent` is on scope or not. I tried `ng-init` instead of `ng-click` and the function gets called for every row in `ng-repeat` hence I assume that `switchEvent` is in scope.

Comment: is your ng repeat working?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes, ng-repeat is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the object with ng-click and access the property inside the click function

```
ng-click="switchEvent(userEvent)"
```

**Controller:**

```
  $scope.switchEvent = function (eventCode) {
        var newLocationHash = "/" + $rootScope.cultureCode + "/navigator/" + eventCode.Event.Code + "/profile";
        $location.path(newLocationHash);
    }
```

Comment: no effect, still the function isn't getting called also no error on console.

Comment: can i see your code via team viewer or create a plunker

Comment: This plnkr shows the same behavior, works for `ng-init` but not for `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

See this line:-

```
<span class="place ">
    {{userEvent.Event.Location}}
</span> |  
<span class="place" ng-click="switchEvent(userEvent.Event.Code)">
   <span>
      {{SwitchEventText}}
   </span>
</span>
```

According to you where are you clicking to call this method

It might not be getting called because you are not clicking at the exact span. may be...

Try changing it to

```
<span class="place ">
    {{userEvent.Event.Location}}
</span> |  
<span class="place" ng-click="switchEvent(userEvent.Event.Code)">
   {{SwitchEventText}}
</span>
```

Remove the inside span

Comment: take a look at the plnkr that I have created http://plnkr.co/edit/63Leeo2M4ArOi45rwg3q. Its close to this code and has same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace accordion.js with http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.2.0.js, it worked for me.